# using facelet1.1.15 (external facelet) in JSF2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have upgrated to JSF2 but still running with facelet1.1.15.
I have these parameters in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I am trying to create my own componet step by step of this example :
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu2/index.html#tip3
everything looks fine but i get an error that it doesn't recognize the tag.

Has it got to do with the facelet 1.1.15? and it works only with VDL?
it there a way to use 1.1.15 and custom components in JSF2?
As well - I use tomcat 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
RichFaces3.3.3 works only with facelet1.1.5 which doesn't support templating.

I had to switch to PrimeFaces where they support VDL and templating:(

Answer (score 1):

JSF 2 has facelets built-in.  It is slightly modified over the stand-alone facelts used with JSF 1.x (to support composite components and the new f:ajax tag, among other things), so you cannot bundle your own facelets implementation with JSF 2.  Try using the new f:ajax tag instead.

Incidentally, RichFaces recently released version 3.3.3 with JSF 2 support.  Maybe they have update Ajax4jsf to support JSF 2 as well.